# How to make AWS EC2 run Procfile?

Tags: deployment, amazon-ec2

I am new to this.  In Heroku, you can create a Procfile that will automatically run when you deploy to production.  What is the equivalent in Amazon Ec2?

I want to automatically run "node app.js" when the instance starts.  Right now I have to login to the console and run it manually.  When I disconnect, the service is stops.

I need it to continue running even when my computer is not connected to Ec2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.  I need to use Forever from NodeJitsue (https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever)

1. Simple install "sudo npm install forever -g" on the Ec2 console
2. Then type "forever start script.js"

That's it!

Comment: I have rails application on EC2 do you have any idea how to run Procfile 
I want to run sidekiq from Procfile